# How to avoid showing all the records before the document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery-bootgrid

I am using `ajax = false`.

How to avoid show all records (more than 100), before starting bootgrid on document-ready event?

Comment: wait for the (window).load event

Answer (score 0):

Use the `loaded` event to check if the grid is loaded with data.[Boot Grid Documentation](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#events)

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this was to set the table style as `display: none;` so it was hidden on initial view and then re-display it in the loaded event.  eg:

```
var grid = $("#myGrid").bootgrid();
grid.on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e) {
    // Show table after bootgrid has finished (stops visual jittering during bootgrid load)
    $("#myGrid").css("display", "");
});
```